# How to manage invite link in private channel?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

***What I did:***

I developed a `Telegram` bot using [TelegrafJS](https://telegraf.js.org/#/) framework. This bot allow the user to subscribe to a paid channel, this channel is privated.

So after that the payment is completed, the bot send the invitation link to let the user join to the channel.

***The problem***

Now suppose that the paying user send the invitation link to another user (who didn't pay), the non-paying user will get the access to the paid channel as if it paid.

Before thinking of a solution, it's necessary to know the limit about the invitation links of Telegram:

- It's not possible to add a user to a channel without invite link;
- It's not possible to create a single-use invite link;
- It's not possible to create a personal invite link (that only one user can use);
- Invite links are cached on Telegram servers and become unstable if you reset them too fast (try resetting a link 2-3 times in 10 seconds using your Telegram app — you'll understand what I mean).

***What I thought as solution***

I thought to show the invite link behind an inline button, so the user will see *CLICK HERE* button for 3 seconds then this will be revoked and another link will be created. This doesn't remove the problem of access to the paying channel without pay a subscription, but it makes life for unfair users more difficult.

Possible other problem: When the user click on the link got:

> Sorry, this channel doesn't seem to exist.

This means that the invite link to the channel is unstable at the moment. It usually happens after clicking *Join* several times in row OR if multiple users are trying to join at the same time.

> Too many attempts, please try again later

It means that the user has clicked on too many invalid invite links recently. Most likely, he had a lot of messages "Sorry, this channel doesn't seem to exist" right before this one or joined too many channels/groups in a row.

***Conclusion***

Is there a more secure way to handle this?

Comment: if you have a database of the paid user's tg handles, can't you just kick the unauthorized users as soon a they join ?

Comment: @Nijeesh I thought to this, unfortunately the Telegram API doesn't support this feature yet for the channel but only for the group.

Comment: you can ban users  from channels.  here is the [api doc](https://core.telegram.org/method/channels.editBanned)

Comment: Is there a way to handle the new users joined using webhook?

Comment: as of today that event for `new_user_joined` is available for groups only i think. but i think, you can write a background job to compare user list  with  in a specific time interval and do the actions with its result.

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy I don't understand why Telegram API doesn't offer a simple feature like this

Comment: I think the bot can kick user from channel lol.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#kickchatmember

Answer (score 2):

Given the limitations of the Telegram API, the best option I can think of is having a unique link which redirects to your bot's invite link.

The bitly API might be something cool to look at for this.

Comment: Interesting solution but the paying user could share the link to others. So the problem isn't full solved...

Answer (score 2):

As for now (Since March 9, 2021) there is a number of methods available to working with limited chat/channel invite links.

You can use createChatInviteLink method to create unique invite link limited to join certain users number.

Please refer to the [official Telegram Bot API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#createchatinvitelink).

Answer (score 1):

How about you generate a link with an expire time on the website where only paid users have access. When they click on the link your Server responds the invite link with a 302 redirect Response.

Example: [Join telegram] [https://myserver.com/generateInviteLink?expiretime={Date.now}+10minutes](https://myserver.com/generateInviteLink?expiretime=%7BDate.now%7D+10minutes)

Response
Http 302 location: T.me/invite/key
When the request time is < expiretime, otherwise you throw an error

The endpoint generateinvitelink should be pw protected aswell. And the Key should be encrypted

I know that an User who is tracking it's http requests will be able to get to the URL but for some users it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Through userbot API your bot can act as a user who is the creator (unlimited admin) of the secret channel. So, this admin can watch the channel's log of subscribers joining/leaving this channel. This log lasts for 24 hours. As soon as the invited user has joined the secret channel, the joinchat-Button can be deleted, and the joinchat URL can be revoked. ElseIf other users join this secret channel, they can be kicked.

Comment: Do you have an example for this? Everyone says that is not possible

Comment: for which step do you mean?

Comment: I mean: could you write some code (at least a simple basic example) to manage this?

Comment: i am not a coder, but have an idea based on my user experience with bots and channels on telegram

Answer (score 0):

You can count number of members in your private chat (channel or group), when count=count+1 create a new invite link.

Comment: It would only work if you are sure nobody leave the group.

Comment: Although bot can catch leave channel events to decrease counter...

Answer (score 0):

Well why not you add them personally from add member option. Ask them to open their privacy setting for a minute and add them. Keep your link private no one will know.